# Why visual studio lib.exe shows same DLL name multiple times when run on *.lib file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, static-libraries

While trying to use `lib.exe` as below, it always shows same DLL name multiple times. This is with every `lib` i have run it with.

What does it signify?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x86>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\Hostx64\x64\lib.exe" /list ucrt.lib
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.21.27702.2
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
```

Comment: It means "this is not useful".  Use lib.exe only on static libraries, like libucrt.lib, this is an import library for ucrtbase.dll.  Dumpbin.exe /exports shows it content.

Comment: @HansPassant - does this mean I can use lib.exe to identify between static library and dll import library of same name? What's your view on answer by JohnCz below where he says I should have used 32 bit version of lib.exe to avoid the above behavior?

Comment: Just try it yourself, type "cd ..\x64" and compare.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped to a conclusion not paying attention to the .lib type. Deleted my "answer". Hans Passant is 100% right.